# Stretch fixed dimension content

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to stretch the picture using the resize bar without changing the size of it.  Also would help if I could somehow keep the aspect ratio too if you could. I have been searching for a few days and trying a bunch of different things.  I'm a self-taught html.  :(  Can someone please guide me?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<style>
body{
text-align:center;
}
.asd{
    width:500px;
    overflow:auto;
    resize:both;
}
.qwer{
    background-color:blue;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

.asdf{
    display:block;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="asd">
  <div class="qwer">
    <div class="asdf"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNn0ZQI8Xa1XrrCNdvIxslsIiIC67HmV6BxVTTgIhEPehwsDU7" width="225" height="225" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Idea**

I'm not 100% sure what exactly do you want to achieve, but if you are looking for a way to make some sort of image resizer - this is how I would approach it.

You need an absolutely positioned image and a relatively positioned div.

Image sits inside the div, which acts as a clip mask. That gives you 2 benefits:

1. You can easily control the visible dimensions by adjusting the div size
2. You can stretch the img tag as much as you want.

**Basic example**

So in terms of a sample code - very basic.

```
<style>
    .parent { 
       position: relative;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       background: yellow;
       margin: 40;
       /* THIS IS THE KEY */
       overflow: hidden;
     }
     .child {
         position: absolute;
         top: -10px;
         left: -10px;
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         background: red;

     }
</style>

<div class="parent">
    <img class="child" src="kitty.png" />
</div>
```

If the stretching is to be dynamic - ie. can me changed, then you can now use javasript to change the `{left, top}` and `{width, height}` of the image to achieve the stretch effect.

If it's supposed to be static - always the same - you can just set the parameters in css.

Comment: I'm trying to make a zoom in and out javascript but I need to be able to zoom in and out without javascript first obviously.  I am working off iframes and am not able to change the width and height of the "picture" but would like to stretch it using container divs.

Comment: For example, the iframe I am adding uses an iframe with a script in there and I am not allowed to change the iframe width, height, or any other properties of it.  I would like to be able to stretch it though because sometimes the iframe is too small.  I would have a zoom out and zoom in javascript that changes the width and height of a containing div that is able to stretch the inside contents.  Is this possible?

Comment: I really don't get 100% your situation. If you can't touch anything inside the iframe then you can't stretch the picture. Unless it is set to 100% size of the iframe and then you would have to resize the iframe. You have to resize something. Either the iframe if the image is auto sizing to parent, or the image itself.

Comment: Can I make a div on the outside of the iframe to be like a box and make that div 100% width and height?  Can I put a div outside the iframe and treat the iframe as a picture? That's what I am trying to do but I'm not too good with code.

Comment: IF you set the iframe to 100% size of its parent, then it will resize with the parent div. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/NjwtE/1/ . So as long as your image within the iframe ALSO resizes with the frame - this will work.

Comment: We are almost there.  That was some good stuff you put there but it doesn't preserve the iframe src.  if you check the source, the 3 boxes are in the same row but in your example, it's in separate rows.

Comment: Can you put 
    width: 800px;
    height:400px;  
in the iframe and make a resize for that?

Comment: Can I maybe turn the iframe and div into an object maybe or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't preserve the source'? In the example, I'm not changing the source. I'm just changing the dimensions. It will work in exactly the same way for 800x400, 200x200 and any other dimension you pick - http://jsfiddle.net/NjwtE/3/

Comment: I want it to work with the set pixels 800 by 400. Right now it works like how the web is displayed. It displays as if the width changes. I don't want that. I want it to shrink or get bigger. Right now the code just shows more. I want it to mimic a zoom function.

Comment: Can someone help me out on this?  I want to be able to stretch the iframe contents while keeping this resolution.  Please don't touch the iframe.  http://jsfiddle.net/NjwtE/5/  I want to enlarge the iframe.  Is this possible?  I can make the javascipt after but I just want someone to figure out how I can stretch this iframe from 800px to 1000px, not by changing the iframe width. Maybe put it inside a block or an object or some sort that's enlargeable? I've been searching for a few days.  Thanks so much.

Comment: That's not possible. You can't stretch websites. You might be able to zoom the page inside the iframe.

Comment: I know you can't stretch websites. That's what iframes are for. I want to stretch the iframe.

Comment: Dude, iframe is just like a website. You can **resize** the iframe to show more of the content inside, but you can't **stretch** it. Iframe is not an image!

Comment: Just found out I can use transform scale. Thanks a lot by the way. Does what I want it to do. Stretches iframe. :) I guess you learned something new too.

Comment: Relax. Anything is possible. You don't know everything. That's why I asked for more help. I appreciate your effort though.

Comment: I did consider that, but the last time I've checked, browser support was pretty poor. Things may be different these days.